# Link to plotly.graph_objects.Figure with intersphinx?

Tags: plotly, python-sphinx, type-hinting

I have set up plotly with intershinx in my conf.py like this:

```
intersphinx_mapping = {
    ...
    'plotly': ('https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/', None),
}
```

Now I try to have my typehints automatically parsed with sphinx autodoc and converted into proper documentation. Intersphinx loads the inventory and it also included the following line (checked with `python -m sphinx.ext.intersphinx https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/objects.inv`):

```
 plotly.graph_objects.Figure              generated/plotly.graph_objects.html#plotly.graph_objects.Figure
```

However, in my documentation, it only says "Figure" without creating the link to plotly.graph_objects.Figure in their docs. But why and how can I debug this?

For context - I have already successfully included the Python standard libs, numpy and matplotlib in my documentation with intersphinx. Moreover, there is no warning while running the code.

**EDIT:**

@steve-piercy: Here is the shortened version of the autodocumented method. I just use the Sphinx directive `autoclass` for its documentation. The docstrings are written in Google Doc style and translated by Napoleon. It has worked fine for all other instances.

```
import plotly.graph_objects

class A:
    def b(self) -> plotly.graph_objects.Figure:
        """
        Returns:
            The plotly figure.
        """
        ...
        fig = plotly.graph_objects.Figure(
            data=[
                plotly.graph_objects.Sankey(
                    arrangement='perpendicular',
                    node=dict(
                        ...
                    ),
                    link=dict(
                        ...
                    )
                )
            ]
        )

        return fig
```

By the way, I tried both `plotly.graph_objects.Figure` and `plotly.graph_objs.Figure`. One issue I have realized is that the actual type does not reside in that package. Instead, there are lots of relative imports from subpackages with leading underscores. This has slightly confused my IDE PyCharm. However, as I am using the full name, I was hoping that just the text is used.

In the past, I had a somehow similar issue with `numpy.typing`. I just imported `numpy` and everything worked fine except the Intersphinx linking. In that case, explicitely importing the subpackage `numpy.typing` solved it for me. In this case, however, I even use the Figure class to create the instance. So it cannot be an issue with a wrong import.

**EDIT 2**:
This is by the way what I mean with an unclickable link. The return type is correctly displayed, it just leads to nowhere. Intersphinx could have issued a warning in that case, couldn't it?

[image]

Comment: Please include your reStructuredText example from your documentation.

Comment: What's your Sphinx version? Sphinx has had a lot of issues with import aliasing in the past (and probably still does).

Comment: It's the latest version, I have updated it a few days ago.